# Best Practice for Adding Lots of Columns to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add many columns to a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
def create_sum_rounds(df, col_name_base):
    '''
    Create a summed column in df from base columns. For example,
    df['sum_foo'] = df['foo_1'] + df['foo_2'] + df['foo_3'] + \
                    df['foo_4'] + df['foo_5'] +
    '''
    out_name = 'sum_' + col_name_base
    df[out_name] = 0.0
    for i in range(1, 6):
        col_name = col_name_base + str(i)
        if col_name in df:
            df[out_name] += df[col_name]
        else:
            logger.error('Col %s not in df' % col_name)

for col in sum_cols_list:
    create_sum_rounds(df, col)
```

Where `sum_cols_list` is a list of ~200 base column names (e.g. `"foo"`), and `df` is a pandas dataframe which includes the base columns extended with 1 through 5 (e.g. `"foo_1", "foo_2", ..., "foo_5"`).

I'm getting a performance warning when I run this snippet:

```
PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
```

I believe this is because creating a new column is actually calling an insert operation behind the scenes. What's the right way to use pd.concat in this case?

Comment: Do you need to retain _all_ the column names at the end of the operation? Do they need to be in Space requirements (and fragmentation) will be easier to manage if the `_sum` and portion (`_1`, `_2`, etc.) columns can be separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your same approach, but instead of operating directly on the `DataFrame`, you'll need to store each output as its own `pd.Series`. Then when all of the computations are done, use `pd.concat` to glue everything back to your original `DataFrame`.

(untested, but should work)

```py
import pandas as pd

def create_sum_rounds(df, col_name_base):
    '''
    Create a summed column in df from base columns. For example,
    df['sum_foo'] = df['foo_1'] + df['foo_2'] + df['foo_3'] + \
                    df['foo_4'] + df['foo_5'] +
    '''
    out = pd.Series(0, name='sum_' + col_name_base, index=df.index)
    for i in range(1, 6):
        col_name = col_name_base + str(i)
        if col_name in df:
            out += df[col_name]
        else:
            logger.error('Col %s not in df' % col_name)
    return out 

col_sums = []
for col in sum_cols_list:
    col_sums.append(create_sum_rounds(df, col))
new_df = pd.concat([df, *col_sums], axis=1)
```

---

Additionally, you can simplify your existing code (if you're willing to forego your logging)

```py
import pandas as pd

def create_sum_rounds(df, col_name_base):
    '''
    Create a summed column in df from base columns. For example,
    df['sum_foo'] = df['foo_1'] + df['foo_2'] + df['foo_3'] + \
                    df['foo_4'] + df['foo_5'] + ...
    '''
    return df.filter(regex=f'{col_name_base}_\d+').sum(axis=1)

col_sums = []
for col in sum_cols_list:
    col_sums.append(create_sum_rounds(df, col))
new_df = pd.concat([df, *col_sums], axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes I kind of thought about this as well. Your solution looks good, only missing a return statement in create_sum_rounds I think :). It's very counterintuitive that creating a bunch of Series objects and concatenating them is more performance efficient than creating a new column that many times.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify :-)

```py
def create_sum_rounds(df, col_name_base):
    '''
    Create a summed column in df from base columns. For example,
    df['sum_foo'] = df['foo_1'] + df['foo_2'] + df['foo_3'] + \
                    df['foo_4'] + df['foo_5'] +
    '''
    out_name = 'sum_' + col_name_base
    df[out_name] = df.loc[:,[x for x in df.columns if x.startswith(col_name_base)]].sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this get you the results you are expecting?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Foo_1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Foo_2' : [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    'Something' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
})

df['Foo_Sum'] = df.filter(like = 'Foo_').sum(axis = 1)
```